# How to make Intersection Observer fire once on page load?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an infinite scroll with Intersection Observer. I'd like it to load more content when user scrolls to `<Box>Loading</Box>`. For some reason on page load Intersection Observer fires two times and I don't understand why and how to fix it. Please help with that.

Here's **codesandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/intersection-observer-5du9ru?file=/src/App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const loadMoreRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const handleObserver = useCallback((entries: any) => {
    const [target] = entries;
    if (target.isIntersecting) {
      setPage((prev) => prev + 1);
    }
  }, []);

  const fetchPosts = useCallback(async (page: number) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=20&_page=${page}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setPosts((prevState) => [...prevState, ...data]);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("fetchProjects:", e);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts(page);
  }, [page, fetchPosts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const option = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 1.0
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleObserver, option);

    if (loadMoreRef.current) observer.observe(loadMoreRef.current);
  }, [handleObserver]);

  return (
    <Stack>
      {posts.map((post, idx) => (
        <Stack>
          <Typography>{idx + 1}</Typography>
          <Typography>{post.title}</Typography>
        </Stack>
      ))}
      <Box ref={loadMoreRef}>Loading</Box>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you using strict mode?

Comment: No. In codesandbox it commented out as well.

Comment: Also, there are much simpler ways to achieve an infinite scroll effect. I literally just wrote a blog article about it [here](https://designly.biz/blog/post/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-component-in-nextjs-react).

Answer (score 0):

You should define your `Intersection Observer` once inside of an on-mount `useEffect`, and also clean it up there on un-mount.

Here's a basic example:

```
const App = () => {
  const observer = useRef(null);
  const observerRef = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const observerCallback = async (e) => {
    if (e.length) {
      setIsVisible(e[0].isIntersecting);
    } else {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (observerRef.current) {
      if (observer.current) {
        observer.current.disconnect();
        observer.current.observe(observerRef.current);
      } else {
        observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback);
        observer.current.observe(observerRef.current);
      }
    }
    return () => observer.current.disconnect();
  }, []);

  // ...
};
```

Also in React 18 Strict Mode, double-rendering happens [on purpose](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development) as a way to identify problematic side-effects. You can ignore it in development or optimize your code.

Here's a simple [Intersection Observer sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-18-2-detect-visible-screen-element-10e7cr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js) which declares the observer once on mount. If you add StrictMode you'll see the alerts firing twice which is to be expected. It simply fires an alert when the green box is totally visible or not.